Strict 2-functoriality of lax-slices of 2-categories
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
I'm currently interested in the homotopy theory of categories "à la Grothendieck", as he developed it in "Pursuing Stacks". I'm trying to try and translate some of the theory to 2-categories and see what remains. Classically, for $Cat$, one can define a series of functors :

given a functor $w:J\to I$, we get $Cat/w : Cat/J\to Cat/I$ mapping $(A,v:A\to J)$ to $(A,wv:A\to I)$, and acting as the identity on morphisms.

$\Theta_I:Cat/I\to \underline{\Hom}(I,Cat)$ (the latter category is the category whose objects are functors $I\to Cat$, morphisms being natural transformations), mapping $(A,v:A\to I)$ to the functor which on objects acts as $F_{(A,v)}:i \mapsto A/^vi$, on morphisms : given $l:(A,v)\to (A',v')$ we get a natural transformation $\eta_{l} : F_{(A,v)}\to F_{(A',v')}$ given by $\eta_v(i):A/^vi\to A'/^{v'}i$ is given by the functor mapping $(a,f:v(a)\to i)\mapsto (l(a),f)$ and the identity on morphisms.  Regarding the notation used : the category $A/^vi$ (or simply $A/I$) has for objects pairs $(a,f:v(a)\to i)$ and morphisms $(a,f)\to (a',f')$ given by $h:a\to a'$ such that $f'v(h)=f$.

Finally, we define a third functor $\Theta_I':\underline{\Hom}(I,Cat)\to Cat/I$ mapping a functor $F:I\to Cat$ to $(\int_I F, \theta_F : \int_I F \to I)$ where the integral denotes the Grothendieck construction of $F$. Similarly, we get a well defined map on morphism, making $\Theta_I'$ a functor indeed.


I'm trying to do roughly the same thing for $2-Cat$ ; Specifically, denote $2-Cat$ the category whose objects are 2-categories ($Cat$-enriched categories) and whose morphisms are strict 2-functors. We also have a the 2-category $\underline{2-Cat}$, whose objects are 2-categories, 1-cells are strict 2-functors, and 2-cells are strict transformations between them. Trying to replicate the paragraph above :

The first functor generalises easily, given a strict 2-functor $w:J\to I$, we get  $2\!-\!Cat/w:2\!-\!Cat/J\to 2\!-\!Cat/I$, defined by the same formulae.

The issues arise already for defining $\Theta_I: 2\!-\!Cat/I\to \underline{\Hom}(I,\underline{2\!-\!Cat})$ (the latter category has objects strict 2-functors, and morphisms strict transformations) ; For one, there are various slices, but assume we care about the "lax slice", so given a 2-functor $v:A\to I$ we take $A/^v_li$ to be the 2-category whose objects are pairs $(a,p:v(a)\to i)$ where $p$ is a 1-cell of $I$, the 1-cells $(a,p)\to (a',p')$ are pairs $(f,\alpha)$ where $f$ is a 1-cell $a\to a'$ of $A$, and $\alpha$ is a 2-cell of $I$ $p'v(f)\Rightarrow p$. It is not clear this assignment is $v\mapsto A/^v_li$ is indeed a strict 2-functor, and further, defining the action on morphisms would require providing a bunch of strict 2-functors (as the component of a transformation) and there again its not clear these are strict 2-functors again. So here if anyone has a reference, or simply knows this I'd love some pointers, because the combinatorics are getting messy and hard to keep track of. Either way, I was trying to avoid lax 2-functors as much as possible, but I will eventually see this through lax or strict I was just hoping someone had done this before.

Regarding the final functor, I have not yet checked anything, I've been focusing my struggles on the previous paragraphs, but briefly, we still have the Grothendieck construction, allowing us to map a strict 2-functor $F:I\to \underline{2\!-\!Cat}$ to a 2-category $\int_I F$ equipped with a strict 2-functor $\int_I F\to I$. I presume making this strictly 2-functorial might not work as nicely as in the 1-categorical case, but I have not tried it yet, as such I can't comment.


So if anyone's got some pointers for the final two paragraphs, I'd really appreciate it.
